# How to perform t test and plot p-values for comparison between groups on a grouped boxplot (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, t-test

I have a data frame, as shown below:

```
> dput(filtered_lymph)
structure(list(cluster = c("CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", 
"CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", 
"CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", 
"CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", 
"CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", 
"CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD4+ Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", 
"CD8+ Effector Tcells", "CD8+ Effector Tcells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", 
"NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", 
"NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", 
"NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", 
"NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", "NK Cells", 
"NK Cells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", 
"Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells", "Progenitor Tcells"
), condition = c("B16_NTX_1", "B16_NTX_2", "B16_NTX_3", "B16_NTX_4", 
"KPC_NTX_1", "KPC_NTX_2", "KPC_NTX_3", "KPC_NTX_4", "KPC_NTX_5", 
"B16_aPD1_1", "B16_aPD1_2", "B16_aPD1_3", "B16_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_1", 
"KPC_aPD1_2", "KPC_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_5", "B16_AC484_1", "B16_AC484_2", 
"B16_AC484_3", "B16_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_1", "KPC_AC484_2", "KPC_AC484_3", 
"KPC_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_5", "KPC_AC484_6", "B16_NTX_1", "B16_NTX_2", 
"B16_NTX_3", "B16_NTX_4", "KPC_NTX_1", "KPC_NTX_2", "KPC_NTX_3", 
"KPC_NTX_4", "KPC_NTX_5", "B16_aPD1_1", "B16_aPD1_2", "B16_aPD1_3", 
"B16_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_1", "KPC_aPD1_2", "KPC_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_5", 
"B16_AC484_1", "B16_AC484_2", "B16_AC484_3", "B16_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_1", 
"KPC_AC484_2", "KPC_AC484_3", "KPC_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_5", "KPC_AC484_6", 
"B16_NTX_1", "B16_NTX_2", "B16_NTX_3", "B16_NTX_4", "KPC_NTX_1", 
"KPC_NTX_2", "KPC_NTX_3", "KPC_NTX_4", "KPC_NTX_5", "B16_aPD1_1", 
"B16_aPD1_2", "B16_aPD1_3", "B16_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_1", "KPC_aPD1_2", 
"KPC_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_5", "B16_AC484_1", "B16_AC484_2", "B16_AC484_3", 
"B16_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_1", "KPC_AC484_2", "KPC_AC484_3", "KPC_AC484_4", 
"KPC_AC484_5", "KPC_AC484_6", "B16_NTX_1", "B16_NTX_2", "B16_NTX_3", 
"B16_NTX_4", "KPC_NTX_1", "KPC_NTX_2", "KPC_NTX_3", "KPC_NTX_4", 
"KPC_NTX_5", "B16_aPD1_1", "B16_aPD1_2", "B16_aPD1_3", "B16_aPD1_4", 
"KPC_aPD1_1", "KPC_aPD1_2", "KPC_aPD1_4", "KPC_aPD1_5", "B16_AC484_1", 
"B16_AC484_2", "B16_AC484_3", "B16_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_1", "KPC_AC484_2", 
"KPC_AC484_3", "KPC_AC484_4", "KPC_AC484_5", "KPC_AC484_6"), 
    `total cells` = c(1.705589084, 1.414617716, 2.009911894, 
    0.857632933, 1.263689975, 1.606186794, 2.006018054, 1.449275362, 
    1.286863271, 4.41495778, 5.954825462, 4.0544723, 4.275011018, 
    1.063829787, 2.304330552, 0.997592019, 1.957585644, 0.386100386, 
    0.500294291, 0.855880729, 0.876460768, 1.538118591, 1.736208345, 
    1.583467525, 1.176075269, 2.027027027, 1.645692159, 14.51062713, 
    4.479622769, 12.61013216, 7.261292167, 3.959561921, 12.55205235, 
    6.218655968, 14.29512516, 3.699731903, 4.680337756, 3.661875428, 
    7.644692046, 6.63287792, 1.968085106, 5.522447358, 10.49191606, 
    3.996737357, 8.273579702, 11.65391407, 12.64494754, 6.385642738, 
    20.17387428, 20.61047326, 22.49060655, 17.37231183, 13.73873874, 
    15.32752501, 3.332458672, 6.635230717, 2.450440529, 3.687821612, 
    4.085930918, 5.770374777, 3.911735206, 5.928853755, 2.252010724, 
    6.899879373, 7.289527721, 4.178272981, 6.170118995, 6.64893617, 
    3.535955503, 6.329549364, 3.752039152, 6.784335356, 5.974102413, 
    7.482054114, 7.429048414, 10.90057958, 9.633155979, 11.54052603, 
    10.68548387, 14.99356499, 16.16650532, 5.510364734, 2.72819131, 
    3.716960352, 5.431675243, 4.886267902, 6.543723974, 6.519558676, 
    5.401844532, 23.21715818, 3.908323281, 3.867214237, 2.69266481, 
    2.732481269, 1.861702128, 7.151370679, 7.258341933, 4.159869494, 
    3.281853282, 3.943496174, 4.389839867, 2.796327212, 4.257690593, 
    5.516661999, 4.911433172, 6.686827957, 8.719433719, 6.808647951
    ), New_Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("NTX", 
    "Anti-PD-1", "AC484"), class = "factor"), Tissue_Expression = c("Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid", 
    "Lymphoid", "Lymphoid")), row.names = c(NA, -108L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

> str(filtered_lymph)
tibble [108 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ cluster          : chr [1:108] "CD4+ Tcells" "CD4+ Tcells" "CD4+ Tcells" "CD4+ Tcells" ...
 $ condition        : chr [1:108] "B16_NTX_1" "B16_NTX_2" "B16_NTX_3" "B16_NTX_4" ...
 $ total cells      : num [1:108] 1.706 1.415 2.01 0.858 1.264 ...
 $ New_Condition    : Factor w/ 3 levels "NTX","Anti-PD-1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Tissue_Expression: chr [1:108] "Lymphoid" "Lymphoid" "Lymphoid" "Lymphoid" ...

> summary(filtered_lymph)
   cluster           condition          total cells     
 Length:108         Length:108         Min.   : 0.3861  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.: 2.6321  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median : 4.5800  
                                       Mean   : 6.0848  
                                       3rd Qu.: 7.2591  
                                       Max.   :23.2172  
   New_Condition Tissue_Expression 
 NTX      :36    Length:108        
 Anti-PD-1:32    Class :character  
 AC484    :40    Mode  :character
```

I am trying to find a way of conducting a two tailed unpaired t-test between the control and test 'New_Condition' variables - this would be between 'NTX' and Anti-PD-1' and another between 'NTX' and 'AC484'. I want this to be calculated for each of the different cell clusters ie. 'CD4+ Tcells', 'Progenitor Tcells' etc.

I then want to be able to plot the p-values above the respective pairs of boxplots on my ggplot - the code for which is detailed below:

```
p_lymph <- ggplot(filtered_lymph, aes(x = cluster, y = `total cells`, fill = New_Condition, color = New_Condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 0.9,linetype="solid", outlier.shape=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=fill_colors) + #These two lines I am changing the legend label from New_Condition (as it is named in the original data column) to Treatment as stated on the original paper
  scale_color_manual(name="Condition", values = outline_colors) +
  theme_minimal()+
  guides(fill="none",color="none")+ #removing the legend
  labs(y="Total cells (%)",
       x=NULL)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=x_lym_labels)+
  theme(
    axis.line=element_line(color="black",linewidth=0.5,linetype="solid"), #adding axis lines
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_line(colour="black",linewidth=0.5),#manually adding in tick breaks
    axis.ticks.y=element_line(colour="black", linewidth=0.5),
    panel.grid=element_blank() #removing grid lines
  )+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,25, by=5),
                         limits=c(0,25), #Adjusting the y-axis breaks
                         labels=c("0","5","10","15","20","25") #customising the y-axis labels
                        )
```

I have previously tried the t.test function:

```
t.test(filtered_lymph$'total cells',filtered_lymph$cluster[filtered_lymph$New_Condition])$p.value
```

however got this error

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(y) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the `ggpubr` package and its `stat_compare_means` function.  I don't usually recommend doing your tests within a plot but if this is all you want it should work for you.

Comment: Again, this is very difficult without reproducible data, which it would be better if you added to your question. We can't run or test your code without reproducible data, e.g. the output from `dput(filtered_lymph)` rather than `str(filtered_lymph)`

Comment: Hi, apologies, my dput(filtered_lymph) data has been included above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as hinted in the comments is to use something like `geom_signif` from `ggsignif`, but you would have to change the structure of your plot to get this to work:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(filtered_lymph, aes(New_Condition, `total cells`,
                           color = New_Condition, fill = after_scale(alpha(color, 0.5)))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c('NTX', 'Anti-PD-1'),
                                 c('NTX', 'AC484')),
              step_increase = 0.1, color = 'black',
              map_signif_level = scales::pvalue_format(add_p = TRUE)) +
  scale_x_discrete('Cluster', expand = c(0.25, 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual("Condition", values = c("#4d4b4c", "#4c517b", "#c63a41")) +
  facet_grid(.~cluster, switch = 'x') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        strip.placement = 'outside')
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the response! I have tried to apply your suggestions into my own code however have gotten this warning message: 

Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`
Caused by error in `if (scales$x$map(comp[1]) == data$group[1] | manual) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
2: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`
Caused by error in `if (scales$x$map(comp[1]) == data$group[1] | manual) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Hi, my post has been previously edited to include my data outputs from dput(filtered_lymph). Apologies for the misunderstanding

Comment: @krw13 see my update. All it took was changing the comparisons to the actual names in your data frame